# Applescript file not found

Tags: applescript

I am using this syntax in my Applescript but I am getting an error file not found. I am sure the file is there. Is there anything wrong with this?

```
set rtfFile to "Macintosh HD:Users:ash:Documents:Core:_Marketing:xlsafe_p.rtf" as alias
```

Comment: Hm, same here ;-)  Now honestly: Check your path!

Comment: my path is correct.. what about Macintosh HD - is that needed?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little handler to check at which point of your path the error occurs:

```
set rtfFile to "Macintosh HD:Users:ash:Documents:Core:_Marketing:xlsafe_p.rtf"
checkPath(rtfFile)

on checkPath(aPathToCheck)
    set oldATID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {":"}
    set pathElements to text items of aPathToCheck
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldATID
    set d to ""
    set tempPath to ""
    repeat with i from 1 to (count pathElements)
        set tempPath to tempPath & d & item i of pathElements
        try
            set foo to tempPath as alias
        on error
            display alert "The path " & return & tempPath & return & "is not valid!" buttons {"OK"}
            return false
        end try
        set d to ":"
    end repeat
    display alert "The path " & return & tempPath & return & "is valid!" buttons {"Yeah!"}
    return true
end checkPath
```

Here it says *The path Macintosh HD:Users:ash is not valid!* because I'm logged in with other credentials than you ;-) Please try this handler and tell us the result!

Enjoy, Michael / Hamburg

Answer (score 0):

Try to choose the file with this, copy the text from the alert, and compare the result.

```
 display alert ((choose file) as text)
```